# Incorrect compiler implementation of iterator blocks?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

Consider the documentation for [IEnumerator.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Current also throws an exception if the last call to MoveNext returned
>   false, which indicates the end of the collection

However, this does not happen with iterator blocks. For example:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var enumerator = GetCounter().GetEnumerator())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            Console.WriteLine (enumerator.Current);
        }
    }
}

static IEnumerable<int> GetCounter()
{
   for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
   {
       yield return count;
   }
}
```

Will simply print 8 times `2`, no exceptions are thrown. Looking at the [compiler transformation](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx), `Current` is simply a field-backed property that always returns the field's value and nothing more. Perhaps it is some form of optimization? Still, this looks like a violation of the contract.

Comment: Oh, I missed that! Apparently it was changed to "undefined". I guess that answers my question, but I can't accept a comment so please make it an answer.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you're correct for [`IEnumerator.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx)'s documentation, [`IEnumerator<T>.Current`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58e146b7.aspx) states that the property is undefined for such a scenario. With your iterator, it returns "2". `List<T>`'s enumerator returns `default(T)`, and `T[]`'s throws an exception. These are all valid implementations, since it's undefined.

> Current is undefined under any of the following conditions:
>
> - The enumerator is positioned before the first element in the    collection, immediately after the enumerator is created. MoveNext must be called to advance the enumerator to the first element of the  collection before reading the value of Current.
> - The last call to    MoveNext returned **false**, which indicates the end of the collection.
> - The enumerator is invalidated due to changes made in the collection,    such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements.

It's worth noting that, even though it implements the interface, the code generated from the `yield return` does not correctly implement `IEnumerator`, since it continues to return `2` in this case:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = GetCounter().GetEnumerator();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine (enumerator.Current);
}
```

(for comparison, `List<T>` does it correctly: if you get `IEnumerator.Current` after the end, it throws an exception, and if you call `IEnumerator<T>.Current` after the end, it returns `default(T)`)

Comment: +1 but we're back to sqaure one aren't we? `IEnumerator` is not implemented correctly, perhaps should I file a bug in connect?

Comment: @OhadSchneider yes, you're right. It's a minor bug, of course, but it is a bug.

Comment: Well, I filed a bug here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806924/iterator-blocks-are-not-implemented-according-to-documentation